# referencing List preferences in email subject

Tags: android

```
private void submit() 
{ 
    SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String listprefs = SP.getString("listprefs","1");              

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String[] recipients = new String[]{""};
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, );
```

I am not sure if this is even possible, but I am needing to have the value that is selected in the list preference to show in the subject of an email. This is part of the code for the submit function of the app.

It works fine the way it is, but I am needing what the user selects to show in the `emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT` line so it will auto populate when the email is generated.

I have tried just about everything I can find on here and through other searches and have not had any luck.

Comment: Is that a `ListPreference` that you're using? I mean, the preference entry that displays a list of single choice items that you need to select in a `PreferenceActivity` and things like that? You should use the proper names so we know exactly what kind of components you're using to make your app.

Comment: Yes, it is a list preference that is being used in a preference activity. I am sorry, I am new to all this and I am still learning all the terms and what does what.

Comment: No problem, I'm just helping you around here. Just a moment, I'll post something. :-)

Comment: See if the code below helps you. And by the way, remember to accept the answers by clicking the green tick. Otherwise, people won't help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the displayed value:

```
int i = listPreferenceObject.findIndexOfValue(listPreferenceObject.getValue());
String optionFromList = (String) listPreferenceObject.getEntries()[i];
...
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, optionFromList);
```

If you want the internal value, just this will do:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, listPreferenceObject.getValue());
```

Alternatively, you could retrieve the value using the PreferenceManager object, like you're doing already. But if you're already in the same activity, it's easier to call the ListPreference I believe.

Of course, I assume you initialized your listpreference object properly. Could be:

```
ListPreference listPreferenceObject = (ListPreference) this.findPreference("listprefs");
```

Comment: I had to use a combination of what I had and what you posted., I also had to put    //TODO End of onCreate Thank you so much for the help